# angular js can not take value from select box

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="canerApp" ng-controller="canerCtrl">

    <button ng-click="click()">
      Button click
    </button>

    <p ng-show="isClicked">

      name=
      <input type="text" ng-model="caner.name">
      <br> surnanme=
      <input type="text" ng-model="caner.surname">
      <br> age

        <select ng-model="caner.age"            
       ng-options="  person.age for person in peole" > </select>    

      <br> Welcome Message: {{ caner.name + " " + caner.surname+" "+caner.age}}
    </p>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module('canerApp', []);

    app.controller('canerCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.caner = {

        name: "caner",
        surname: "aydin",

age: "22",
      };

      $scope.peole = [{
        age: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
      }, {
        age: 2,
        name: 'Alice'
      }, {
        age: 3,
        name: 'Steve'
      }];

      $scope.isClicked = true;    

      $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.isClicked = !$scope.isClicked;
      };
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

can be seen here

when i select 3 for example, output becomes

**Welcome Message: caner aydin [object Object]**

i get the value here

```
  <select ng-model="caner.age"

   ng-options="  person.age for person in peole" >
```

in contrller

```
 $scope.peole = [{
        age: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
      }, {
        age: 2,
        name: 'Alice'
      }, {
        age: 3,
        name: 'Steve'
      }];
```

it should give 3 , not object object output. i put to caner.age to give output.

Answer (score 1):

Change your drop-down tag to the following.

```
<select ng-model="caner.age"

       ng-options="  person.age as person.age for person in peole" >







    </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The  will bind the object to your ng-model. 
Meaning that caner.age will be

```
{
    age: 3,
    name: 'Steve'
}
```

If you use

```
 Welcome Message: {{ caner.name + " " + caner.surname+" "+caner.age.age}}
```

it should work. I hope this will guide you to on how to refactor your code.

Answer (score 0):

Change caner.age.age instead of caner.age

```js
var app = angular.module('canerApp', []);

    app.controller('canerCtrl', function($scope) {

      $scope.caner = {

        name: "caner",
        surname: "aydin",

age: "22",
      };

      $scope.peole = [{
        age: 1,
        name: 'Bob'
      }, {
        age: 2,
        name: 'Alice'
      }, {
        age: 3,
        name: 'Steve'
      }];





      $scope.isClicked = true;




      $scope.click = function() {
        $scope.isClicked = !$scope.isClicked;
      };
    });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div ng-app="canerApp" ng-controller="canerCtrl">

    <button ng-click="click()">
      Button click
    </button>

    <p ng-show="isClicked">

      name=
      <input type="text" ng-model="caner.name">
      <br> surnanme=
      <input type="text" ng-model="caner.surname">
      <br> age

        <select ng-model="caner.age"

       ng-options="person.age for person in peole" >







        </select>


      <br> Welcome Message: {{ caner.name + " " + caner.surname+" "+caner.age.age}}
    </p>


  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your problem:**

You are binding the object `person` to the ng-model `caner.age` with your ng-options :

```
<select ng-model="caner.age"
   ng-options="person.age for person in peole" >
</select>
```

That's why you are getting [Object][Object] in your angular expression `{{caner.age}}`

**Solution:**

While changing it to `{{caner.age.age}}` is a valid solution, you might want to consider correcting your ng-model binding to bind the actual age value instead of the person object like this :

```
<select ng-model="caner.age"
   ng-options="person.age as person.age for person in peole" >
</select>
```

For why it has to be written this way, see for documentations : [ng-options documentations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)